# linux c++. Возврат к прерванному контексту после обработки сигнала

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность

Есть метод вида:

```
ResultType Getter::get()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mx);
  Reader::readData();
}
```

Есть обработчик сигнала:

```
std::list<CommandMethod<>> Events;
std::mutex              lock;
std::condition_variable check;
bool notified=false;
void EventDispatcherThread()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(lock);
        while (!notified)
            check.wait(locker);
        while (Events.size() > 0)
        {
            Events.front()();
            Events.pop_front();
        }
        notified = false;
    }
}

CommandMethod<> event(&controller,&Controller::EventHandler, SIGSYS);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::thread sed_thread(&EventDispatcherThread);
    sed_thread.detach();
    std::signal(SIGSYS, [](int sig)->void {
        std::unique_lock < std::mutex> lock(g_lock);
        Events.push_back(event);
        notified = true;
        g_check.notify_all();
    });
    controller.main(argc, argv);
}
```

метод класса, который дергает обработчик:

```
Controller::EventHandler(int sig)
{
   /*......*/
   Getter::get();
}
```

метод класса, который исполняется в главном потоке.

```
Controller::main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   /*......*/
   Getter::get();
}
```

Проблема в том, что сигнал срабатывющий, пока залочен мютекс в `Getter::get()` главного потока в методе `Controller::main(int argc, char *argv[])` прерывает его выполнение, и после обработки сигнала переходит к выполнению `void EventDispatcherThread()`, который в свою очередь через `Controller::EventHandler(int sig)` тоже вызывает `Getter::get()`, тем самым возникает взаимоблокировка. Я понимаю, что обработчик сигнала может прервать контекст в любой момент, но как заставить его вернуться к прерванному контексту(в метод `Controller::main(int argc, char *argv[])`) после обработки сигнала, а не после обработки `EventDispatcherThread()`

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в обработчике сигнала нельзя делать чего то сложнее, чем поменять примитивную переменную. А выделять память уже не стоит. У Вас же идет попытка захватить мьютекс.

Comment: Вот список того, что можно вызывать из обработчика -- [signal-safety - async-signal-safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо avp, за правильную ссылку. `g_check.notify_all();` не является безопасной для обработчика сигналов. Поток `Controller::EventHandler(int sig)` пробуждался перед завершением обработчика сигнала, и ,видимо, по этой причине получал приоритет над основным потоком. Реализовал следующим образом:

```
sem_t sem;
void EventDispatcherThread()
{
    while (1)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        controller.EventHandler(SIGSYS);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        sem_wait(&sem);
    std::thread sed_thread(&EventDispatcherThread);
    sed_thread.detach();
    std::signal(SIGSYS, [](int sig)->void {
         sem_post(&sem);

    });
    controller.main(argc, argv);
}
```

Все оказалось намного проще.

Вопрос такого же плана: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117959/waking-up-thread-from-signal-handler

Comment: создай семофор сразу с нулевым значением `sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);` вместо этого бессмысленного цикла...